# C# if else is not executing

Tags: c#, if-statement

[image]

the `if else` statements don't execute... here is the code:

***this should compute the discount and the total amount of item purchsed depending on the date it was paid***

```
        DateTime dPurchase, dPaid;
        int amount;
        double discount, totalAmount, days;

        S.Write("Purchase amount: ");
        amount = Convert.ToInt16(S.ReadLine());
        S.Write("Date Purchased: ");
        dPurchase = Convert.ToDateTime(S.ReadLine());
        S.Write("Date to be Paid: ");
        dPaid = Convert.ToDateTime(S.ReadLine());

        days = dPaid.Subtract(dPurchase).TotalDays;

        if (days <= 10) 
        {
            discount = amount * 0.2;
            totalAmount = amount - discount;
            S.Write("Discount: " + discount + "\nTotal Amount: " + totalAmount);
        }
        else if (days <= 25)
        {
            discount = amount * 0.15;
            totalAmount = amount - discount;
            S.Write("Discount: " + discount + "\nTotal Amount: " + totalAmount);
        }
        else if (days <= 35)
        {
            discount = amount * 0.1;
            totalAmount = amount - discount;
            S.Write("Discount: " + discount + "\nTotal Amount: " + totalAmount);
        }
        else if (days <= 45)
        {
            discount = amount * 0.05;
            totalAmount = amount - discount;
            S.Write("Discount: " + discount + "\nTotal Amount: " + totalAmount);
        }
        else 
        {
            discount = 0;
            totalAmount = amount;
        }
        S.Write("Days: " + days + "\n");
        S.Write("First Term: " + dPurchase.Date.AddDays(1) + " to " + dPurchase.Date.AddDays(10) + "\n");
        S.Write("Second Term: " + dPurchase.Date.AddDays(11) + " to " + dPurchase.Date.AddDays(25) + "\n");
        S.Write("Third Term: " + dPurchase.Date.AddDays(26) + " to " + dPurchase.Date.AddDays(35) + "\n");
        S.Write("Fourth Term: " + dPurchase.Date.AddDays(36) + " to " + dPurchase.Date.AddDays(45) + "\n");
        S.Write("Fifth Term: " + dPurchase.Date.AddDays(46) + " to " + dPurchase.Date.AddDays(60) + "\n");
        S.ReadKey();
```

**lines after the `if..else` statements are executing**

Comment: what is `S.Write()`?

Comment: @thumbmunkeys its like Console.Write();

Comment: Debug it......... Watch "days" step by step.....

Comment: @SethAlilio what is the value of `days` ?

Comment: What makes you think the if-statements are not executed? What result do you expect and what result do you get? What data do you use?

Comment: Do you have this code within a try-catch block, and perhaps an exception is being thrown prior to the if-else blocks, preventing them from executing?

Comment: @user3185569 i get the value of days through this code: days = dPaid.Subtract(dPurchase).TotalDays;

Comment: @rucamzu: Lines after the if-statements are executing, so no exception.

Comment: @Martin Mulder S.Write("Discount: " + discount + "\nTotal Amount: " + totalAmount); should be displayed but it wont

Comment: @rucamzu no try-catch..just pure if else

Comment: BTW (though this is off-topic), the only thing depending on the number of days is the discount computation. Refactor it out into a separate function, and you'll get much cleaner code.

Comment: In your example  `days` = `46`. If would expect that only the last else-block is executed. Do you expect something differently?

Comment: If you had followed the DRY rule you would not face this problem

Answer (score 4):

If you follow the DRY rule

> **D**on't **R**epeat **Y**oursef

you will not face this kind of problems

```
DateTime dPurchase, dPaid;
int amount;
double? discount = null;
double totalAmount, days;

S.Write("Purchase amount: ");
amount = Convert.ToInt16(S.ReadLine());
S.Write("Date Purchased: ");
dPurchase = Convert.ToDateTime(S.ReadLine());
S.Write("Date to be Paid: ");
dPaid = Convert.ToDateTime(S.ReadLine());

days = dPaid.Subtract(dPurchase).TotalDays;

if (days <= 10) 
    discount = amount * 0.2;
else if (days <= 25)
    discount = amount * 0.15;
else if (days <= 35)
    discount = amount * 0.1;
else if (days <= 45)
    discount = amount * 0.05;

totalAmount = amount - discount.GetValueOrDefault();    

if (discount.HasValue)
  S.Write("Discount: " + discount.Value );

S.Write( "Total Amount: " + totalAmount);

S.Write("Days: " + days + "\n");
S.Write("First Term: " + dPurchase.Date.AddDays(1) + " to " + dPurchase.Date.AddDays(10) + "\n");
S.Write("Second Term: " + dPurchase.Date.AddDays(11) + " to " + dPurchase.Date.AddDays(25) + "\n");
S.Write("Third Term: " + dPurchase.Date.AddDays(26) + " to " + dPurchase.Date.AddDays(35) + "\n");
S.Write("Fourth Term: " + dPurchase.Date.AddDays(36) + " to " + dPurchase.Date.AddDays(45) + "\n");
S.Write("Fifth Term: " + dPurchase.Date.AddDays(46) + " to " + dPurchase.Date.AddDays(60) + "\n");
S.ReadKey();
```

As you can see it has less code, is easier to read/maintain and less error prone.

Answer (score 1):

That is because the `days` value is greater than 45. Have you tried to set the `days` variable manually to a value less than the 45?

It is working fine for me.

Comment: it works fine if days is less than 45. discount and total amount wont appear beyond 45

Answer (score 1):

You expect that the line `S.Write("Discount: " + discount + "\nTotal Amount: " + totalAmount);` is executed. In your example, the `days` equals to `46.

Only the last else-block is execute, so that line `S.Write(...)` is not.

Why?

- The first if-block is only executed if `days` is less than or equal to 10. 46 is larger than 10, so it is skipped.
- The second if-block is only executed if `days` is greater than 10 and less than

  25. 46 is larger than 25, so it is skipped.
- The third if-block is only executed if `days` is greater than 25 and less than 35. 46 is larger than 35, so it is skipped.
- The fourth if-block is only executed if `days` is greater than 35 and less than 45. 46 is larger than 25, so it is skipped.

Comment: oh i forgot the S.Write ... (basic programmer errors) THANKS MAN :D

Comment: You are welcome. If you think this answer is the right answer, please reward it by checking the gray tick on the left of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant to place this line after the last else:

```
else
{
    discount = 0;
    totalAmount = amount;
}
Console.WriteLine("Discount: " + discount + "\nTotal Amount: " + totalAmount);
```

and remove it from the other if blocks. So that it gets displayed in all cases.